# How to Print Specific Data attribute in .txt

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a css grid with boxes that once being clicked changes from white to red and then to green and could get back to the initial state, it also has a data attribute (each box) that changes from defaultWhite state to defaultRed and defaultGreen depending on the clicking of the boxes. For now that works, now I want to print a .txt report with the selections. I've researched and did some code but is not working now.

**Goals:**

- Once clicked the download button, get a .txt sheet with all the values for all the 52 boxes and their data (default, if its red or if its green)

```js
readyfunction download(filename, stateData) {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);

            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            element.click();

            document.body.removeChild(element);
            }

            // Start file download.
            document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
            // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
            var text = document.getElementById("sheW1");
            var stateData = text.getAttribute('data');
            var filename = "Report.txt";
            download(filename, stateData);
            }, false);
```

```css
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none; 
}

.generalWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ;
    position:
}

.boxes-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1280px;
    background-color: ;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title" "sheW1 sheW2 sheW3 sheW4 sheW5 sheW6 sheW7 sheW8 sheW9 sheW10 sheW11 sheW12 sheW13 sheW14" "sheW52 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW15" "sheW51 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW16" "sheW50 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW17" "sheW49 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW18" "sheW48 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW19" "sheW47 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW20" "sheW46 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW21" "sheW45 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW22" "sheW44 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW23" "sheW43 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW24" "sheW42 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW25" "sheW41 Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter Letter sheW26" "sheW40 sheW39 sheW38 sheW37 sheW36 sheW35 sheW34 sheW33 sheW32 sheW31 sheW30 sheW29 sheW28 sheW27";
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    font-family: sans-serif, helvetica;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: ;
}

.Title {
    grid-area: Title;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#sheW1 { grid-area: sheW1;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW2 { grid-area: sheW2;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW3 { grid-area: sheW3;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW4 { grid-area: sheW4;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW5 { grid-area: sheW5;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW6 { grid-area: sheW6;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW7 { grid-area: sheW7;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW8 { grid-area: sheW8;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW9 { grid-area: sheW9;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW10 { grid-area: sheW10;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW11 { grid-area: sheW11;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW12 { grid-area: sheW12;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW13 { grid-area: sheW13;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW14 { grid-area: sheW14;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW15 { grid-area: sheW15;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW16 { grid-area: sheW16;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW17 { grid-area: sheW17;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW18 { grid-area: sheW18;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW19 { grid-area: sheW19;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW20 { grid-area: sheW20;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW21 { grid-area: sheW21;
text-align: center;}

#sheW22 { grid-area: sheW22;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW23 { grid-area: sheW23;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW24 { grid-area: sheW24;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW25 { grid-area: sheW25;
text-align: center;}

#sheW26 { grid-area: sheW26;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW27 { grid-area: sheW27;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW28 { grid-area: sheW28;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW29 { grid-area: sheW29;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW30 { grid-area: sheW30;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW31 { grid-area: sheW31;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW32 { grid-area: sheW32;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW33 { grid-area: sheW33;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW34 { grid-area: sheW34;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW35 { grid-area: sheW35;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW36 { grid-area: sheW36;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW37 { grid-area: sheW37;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW38 { grid-area: sheW38;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW39 { grid-area: sheW39;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW40 { grid-area: sheW40;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW41 { grid-area: sheW41;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW42 { grid-area: sheW42;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW43 { grid-area: sheW43;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW44 { grid-area: sheW44;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW45 { grid-area: sheW45;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW46 { grid-area: sheW46;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW47 { grid-area: sheW47;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW48 { grid-area: sheW48;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW49 { grid-area: sheW49;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW50 { grid-area: sheW50;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW51 { grid-area: sheW51;
text-align: center;
}

#sheW52 { grid-area: sheW52;
text-align: center;
}

.Letter { grid-area: Letter;
border: 1px solid darkgrey;
text-align: center;
}

.letterCenter {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 200px;
    color: darkslateblue;
}

.changeColor {
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.changeColor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.enableHover:hover {
    background-color:darkgrey;
    color: white;
}

.changeColor.green {
    background-color:forestgreen;
    color: white;
}

.changeColor.red {
    background-color:crimson;
    color: white;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  .grid-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }

  .Title {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 14;
  }

  #sheW1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW3 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW4 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 4;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW5 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 5;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW6 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 6;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW7 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 7;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW8 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 8;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW9 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 9;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW10 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 10;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW11 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 11;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW12 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 12;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW13 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 13;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW14 {
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW15 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW16 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW17 {
    -ms-grid-row: 5;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW18 {
    -ms-grid-row: 6;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW19 {
    -ms-grid-row: 7;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW20 {
    -ms-grid-row: 8;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW21 {
    -ms-grid-row: 9;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW22 {
    -ms-grid-row: 10;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW23 {
    -ms-grid-row: 11;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW24 {
    -ms-grid-row: 12;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW25 {
    -ms-grid-row: 13;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW26 {
    -ms-grid-row: 14;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW27 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 14;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW28 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 13;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW29 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 12;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW30 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 11;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW31 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 10;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW32 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 9;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW33 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 8;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW34 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 7;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW35 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 6;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW36 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 5;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW37 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 4;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW38 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW39 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW40 {
    -ms-grid-row: 15;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW41 {
    -ms-grid-row: 14;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW42 {
    -ms-grid-row: 13;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW43 {
    -ms-grid-row: 12;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW44 {
    -ms-grid-row: 11;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW45 {
    -ms-grid-row: 10;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW46 {
    -ms-grid-row: 9;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW47 {
    -ms-grid-row: 8;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW48 {
    -ms-grid-row: 7;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW49 {
    -ms-grid-row: 6;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW50 {
    -ms-grid-row: 5;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW51 {
    -ms-grid-row: 4;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  #sheW52 {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  }

  .Letter {
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 12;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>S test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="S test">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        const changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('changeColor');

        Array.from(changeColor).forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        item = event.target;

        if (item.classList.contains('green')) {
            item.classList.remove('green');
            item.classList.add('red');
            item.setAttribute('data', 'defaultRed');
        } else if(item.classList.contains('red')) {
            item.classList.remove('red');
            item.classList.add('enableHover');
            item.setAttribute('data', 'defaultWhite');
        } else {
            item.classList.add('green');
            item.classList.remove('enableHover');
            item.setAttribute('data', 'defaultGreen');
        }
        });
        });
        });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/printReport.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
   
    <div class="generalWrapper">  
      <div class="boxes-container">  
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="Title">SHE</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW1" data="defaultWhite">1</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW2" data="defaultWhite">2</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW3" data="defaultWhite">3</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW4" data="defaultWhite">4</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW5" data="defaultWhite">5</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW6" data="defaultWhite">6</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW7" data="defaultWhite">7</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW8" data="defaultWhite">8</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW9" data="defaultWhite">9</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW10" data="defaultWhite">10</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW11" data="defaultWhite">11</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW12" data="defaultWhite">12</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW13" data="defaultWhite">13</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW14" data="defaultWhite">14</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW15" data="defaultWhite">15</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW16" data="defaultWhite">16</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW17" data="defaultWhite">17</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW18" data="defaultWhite">18</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW19" data="defaultWhite">19</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW20" data="defaultWhite">20</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW21" data="defaultWhite">21</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW22" data="defaultWhite">22</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW23" data="defaultWhite">23</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW24" data="defaultWhite">24</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW25" data="defaultWhite">25</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW26" data="defaultWhite">26</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW27" data="defaultWhite">27</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW28" data="defaultWhite">28</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW29" data="defaultWhite">29</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW30" data="defaultWhite">30</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW31" data="defaultWhite">31</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW32" data="defaultWhite">32</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW33" data="defaultWhite">33</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW34" data="defaultWhite">34</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW35" data="defaultWhite">35</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW36" data="defaultWhite">36</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW37" data="defaultWhite">37</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW38" data="defaultWhite">38</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW39" data="defaultWhite">39</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW40" data="defaultWhite">40</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW41" data="defaultWhite">41</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW42" data="defaultWhite">42</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW43" data="defaultWhite">43</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW44" data="defaultWhite">44</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW45" data="defaultWhite">45</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW46" data="defaultWhite">46</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW47" data="defaultWhite">47</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW48" data="defaultWhite">48</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW48" data="defaultWhite">48</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW48" data="defaultWhite">48</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW49" data="defaultWhite">49</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW50" data="defaultWhite">50</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW51" data="defaultWhite">51</div>
          <div class="changeColor enableHover" id="sheW52" data="defaultWhite">52</div>
          <div class="Letter">
            <div class="letterCenter">S</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    
    <input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Download Report"/>
    </div>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you checked the console from your browser for errors?

Comment: hello @reporter yes is giving me an error on line 1 of the js printReport file, not sure why.

I mean it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" but not sure why?

Ok so, you have 52 boxes, you can tick them and change their state from white to green or red or get back to white. it also has a data attribute for each one. that also changes from defaultWhite to defaultRed or defaultGreen, I just want to print it somehow in the .txt file like
sheW1 = defaultWhite
sheW2 = defaultRed
Assuming i ticked twice the box 2 to turn it red.

Right now is not even printing anything :(!